# Need help (VBA or formula?) returning only specific instances of a partial number string

Tags: excel-formula

**Background:** A 66k+ row Excel table contains all customer ID #'s and business names. Most CID's have 5-8 digits, but a few thousand are from several legacy systems which used leading zeros -one, two, or even three.  So the table has many instances of different clients with extremely similar CID's like 4212, 04212, 004212, etc. In this table to make all clients searchable, the CID's are all stored as text -to keep leading zeros.

**Help:** I have to create a lookup like below where a user can enter a CID, and a table will populate all similar CIDs and business names. I assume this will be some sort of array formula. It will need to filter out all CIDs that contain the entered CID as only part of the full # (ie: 4212 would NOT return 14212 but would return 4212 and 04212).  I have no idea how to achieve this.  HELP!

[image]

Comment: Do you have Office 365?

Comment: Yes, we are all on Office 365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the largest length of a CID, then you can filter based on the padded CID. For example, if the largest length were 7 digits such as `1234567`, then you could pad three zeros to the left with `=TEXT([CID],"000000000")` which would produce `0001234567`. This technique can be used to force all of your CID's to the same padding.

That can be used as your lookup value in an Excel 365 (or 2021) formula like this:

```
=FILTER(F2:F3997,ISNUMBER(FIND(TEXT(B4,"0000000000"),TEXT(F2:F3997,"0000000000"))))
```

that searches for the padded version of B4 within the padded CID#s (cells F2:F3997 in this example).

So, for example, if your CID's were in F2:F3997 and your account names were in G2:G3997, you could put the above formula in your cell C4 and this formula in cell D4:

```
=XLOOKUP(C4#,F2:F3997,G2:G3997,,0)
```

Each of these formulas will spill the result below.

[image]

> *I made up account names by simply taking the padded DEC2HEX of the CID*
> *so that I could check the results.*

Comment: Interesting with the 0 padding. I case there is an other charakter than numbers in the string it will not work. In that case I discovered this formula will do it (in any case):
=REPT("0";10-LEN(C3))&C3

Comment: @Prema - nice solution. I suppose `TEXT(--[CID],"0000000000")` would also be a good precaution.

Comment: Did you try that? It is not working for me. With letters, it gives a value error.
=TEXT(--C16;"0000000000")

Comment: Yes, but actually, I never got an error. I just realized that I misunderstood your point - I thought you meant something like "  47", but you mean something like "x47". This indeed creates an error. In which case, your `=REPT("0";10-LEN(C3))&C3` is an excellent way to extend this solution to non-numerical CID's. It is also a great way to make non-numeric padding.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tested your solution and it works for me.  I also came up with another solution where I created another column of all CIDs stripped of leading zeros and ran a filter formula on that to pull the text CIDs and account names. Both work.